# Knockout Binding Not Working with jQueryUI Dialogue

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

My viewModel has an array called 'Items'. I want to display the contents of 'Items' using a foreach binding. Everything works fine when I use regular HTML. But does not work with a dialogue box which I created using jQueryUI.

HTML:

```
<div id="skus0">
  <div id="skus1">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Items">
      <li data-bind="text:Name"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="openQryItems" class="btn btn-info" value="Open" data-bind="click:openQueryItems" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// my view model
var viewModel = {
  Items: [{Name:'Soap'},{Name:'Toothpaste'}] 
};

// JS to configure dialogue
$("#skus1").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 500,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "OK": function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "Cancel": function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});

// for mapping my model using ko.mapping plugin
var zub = zub || {};
zub.initModel = function (model) {
  zub.cycleCountModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
  zub.cycleCountModel.openQueryItems = function () {
    $("#skus1").dialog("open");
  }
  ko.applyBindings(zub.cycleCountModel, $("#skus0")[0]);
}

zub.initModel(viewModel);
```

I have created a fiddle here [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harrobbed/n3Ltveue/)

Comment: @Matt.kaaj I have to make use of ko.mapping and the namespace. my real world model is very big and ko.mapping does help me out with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.fn.dialog` removes the element from its place in the DOM and places it in a new container; this is how it can create a floating window. The problem with this happening is that it breaks data binding, since the dialog DOM is no-longer nested within the top-level data-bound DOM.

Moving the dialog initialization to *after* `ko.applyBindings` will enable `dialog` to yank stuff out of the DOM *after* the list is populated. Of course, this means that after that point, future changes will still not be reflected, which may be important if you're wanting the opened dialog to change automatically.

If you are wanting the dialog contents to be fully dynamic, you could create a binding handler; we did this in our project. Here's a rough outline of how we did this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingCtx) {
    var bindingValues = valueAccessor();
    var hasAppliedBindings = false;
    var elem = $(element);
    var options = {
      id: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(bindingValues.id),
      title: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(bindingValues.title),
      // etc...
      onOpen: function () {
        if (!hasAppliedBindings) {
          hasAppliedBindings = true;
          var childCtx = bindingCtx.createChildContext(viewModel);
          ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childCtx, element);
        }
      }
    };

    elem.dialog(options);
  }

  return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
}
```

...which we used like this:

```
<div data-bind="dialog: { title: 'some title', id: 'foo', ... }">
  <!-- dialog contents -->
</div>
```

What `return { controlsDescendantBindings: true }` does is makes sure that outer bindings do not affect anything using the `dialog` binding handler. Then we create our own Knockout binding "island" after it is pulled out of the DOM, based on the original view model.

Although in our project we also used hybrid jQuery+Knockout, I would highly recommend you avoid this whenever possible. There were so many hacks we had to employ to sustain this type of application. The very best thing you should do is prefer Knockout binding handlers (and I think it has a "component" concept now which I haven't played with) over DOM manipulations to avoid buggy UI management.

Comment: thank you! went home and tried it. Got it working. All I had to do was to initialize the dialog after ko.applyBindings as you suggested.